# Using Positional Placeholders with WHERE IN Returns Only One Result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to incorporate a WHERE IN statement into an already-working query using PDO. I've gone through and dynamically created positional placeholders using the count of an indexed array, and looped through said array to bind each value. However when this is all said and done I'm only getting one result, specifically a result matching the last value I dynamically bound.

To add to this, if I simply implode `$arrayToCheck` with a comma as a delimiter in place of `$placeholderSpots`, I get the full 24 results I'm expecting.

```
$arrayToCheck = json_decode($listFromDatabase); //This is a Python List converted to a string using Python's json.dumps, which was then passed into a database table.
$timePeriod = 0;
$rowLimit = 2500;

$placeholderSpots = implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($arrayToCheck), "?"));

$toPull = $GLOBALS['MainDatabase']->prepare("SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE timecolumn >= ? AND idcolumn IN ($placeholderSpots) ORDER BY timecolumn DESC LIMIT ?");
$toPull->bindParam(1, $timePeriod, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$tempCounter = 2;
foreach ($arrayToCheck as $eachID) {
    
    $toPull->bindParam($tempCounter, $eachID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $tempCounter++;
    
}

$toPull->bindParam($tempCounter, $rowLimit, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($toPull->execute()) {
    
    while ($pulledData = $toPull->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //Data Is Processed Here
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, if you're bindParam already, why aren't you Binding the `$placeHolderSpots` as well?  Have you echo'ed the `$placeHolderSpots` to ensure you're getting what you expected out of it?

Comment: @Jimithus I may be misunderstanding but I don't think you can generate positional placeholders using bind. And yes I've confirmed that the prepare statement has the correct number of placeholders. Unfortunately I can't see what the final statement looks like but the lack of an error confirms that the correct number of parameters are being passed in and an echo of `$eachID` in the foreach loop shows that it's as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `bindParam()` with `bindValue()`.

```
foreach ($arrayToCheck as $eachID) {
    $toPull->bindValue($tempCounter++, $eachID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

The [`bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method bind by reference to the variable. You assign a new value each time to the same variable when looping over the array, so the variable doesn't change, only the value does. The end result is that you have bound the same variable multiple times that holds the last value from the array.